# How to describe kubernetes resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to get metadata for a given kubernetes resource. Similar to a `describe` for a REST end-point.

Is there a `kubectl` to get all possible things that I could provide for any k8s resource ?

For example for the deployment resource, it could be something like this.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <type:String> 
        <desc: name for the deployment>
  namespace: <type:String>
             <desc: Valid namespace>
  annotations:
    ...
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `kubectl explain` CLI command:

> This command describes the fields associated with each supported API
>   resource. Fields are identified via a simple JSONPath identifier:
>
> `<type>.<fieldName>[.<fieldName>]`
>
> Add the `--recursive` flag to display all of the fields at once without descriptions. Information about each field is retrieved from the server in OpenAPI format.

Example to view all *Deployment* associated fields:

`kubectl explain deployment --recursive`

You can dig into specific fields:

`kubectl explain deployment.spec.template`

You can also rely on [Kubernetes API Reference Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#deployment-v1-apps).

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with OpenApi/Swagger? Try to open the following file in swagger-ui https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/master/api/openapi-spec/swagger.json

If you have a live kubernetes api available the file should be available under /openapi/v2 like they describe here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#openapi-and-swagger-definitions